# Creating a welcome mail for users when Google Marketplace App is installed

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We have a new app in the Google Marketplace - and I am struggling to find out how to get an email sent to the Admin who installs the Application. On so many apps you do the install - and then voila - in your mailbox is the Welcome mail from them - furthering the customer experience.

How do we get that email sent, as I cannot even see who the Admin user is that installed the Application?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Is your App an Add-On developed with Apps Script?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can configure an "Admin Config URL" in the Marketplace Listing page that is suggested to the admin during the install.
2. you can wait for the first login to your app, check your users DB and send email if it is the first time.